# PHP file works on draft page but not once published

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some javascript that gets a PHP file from my root folder with this line: `xhttp.open("GET", "getcollection.php")`

It works perfectly fine when my page is in draft mode, but as soon as I publish the page it no longer works.

I have trawled through a lot of different questions and answers to no avail so I thought I would ask myself.

I believe that I need to either move the PHP file from my root to my themes directory but I haven't yet had any luck with anywhere I have moved it. Maybe I need to add an `include(getcollection.php)` to another file somewhere in my theme.

Essentially I think what I am asking is, where do I place my PHP file in order for it to be found using `xhttp.open("GET", "getcollection.php")`

If you need to see all my javascript and PHP files then I can provide them, I just didn't want to bloat my question out if it wasn't necessary.

I am working with WordPress. I do have plugin called wpCode also but I cannot seem to get it to work through that either.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to help me out, and I am beginning my journey into javascript / PHP at the moment so apologies for my newbieness.

Comment: are you using javascript to open a php file for a reason? why not use php `include` function?

Comment: The JavaScript function is called on selection of a drop down item, within the JavaScript it looks up a PHP file which gets data from my database and displays what it needs to based on the data retrieved. If I am totally honest I am not aware of the include function or how it's used as of yet.

Comment: are you putting this inside the theme in a php file?

Comment: Currently it's just in the root directly because when creating it I was on a draft page and it worked fine there. After publishing it stopped, I tried it in my themes directory but couldn't get it working again, i tried a few folders within the themes directory too

Comment: The JavaScript is in a plugin I have to create JavaScript, HTML, and CSS code

Answer (score 0):

You can either include it in a php file:

```
<?php include get_template_directory() . '/getcollection.php';?>
```

or define the theme root in a php that your javascript file can read

```
<?php $theme_root = esc_js( get_template_directory_uri() );?>
```

either way you need to fine the full url to the file from the root of theme

Comment: This is where I think I am being a bit dumb but when you say, "include it in a PHP file", which PHP file do you mean? I have tried functions.php, index.php and header.php in my themes directory, but I must be missing something.

Comment: Or do you put that `include` statement within the javascript?

Comment: what file is your dropdown in now?

Comment: It is in a PHP file in a plugin called WPCode

Comment: so its in the header? where is the plugin being called?

Comment: It's saved to a shortcode which I use on the page.

Comment: so add to your shortcode this php include

Comment: I am just not getting it at the minute, it's nearly 3 am where I am now so I'm going to go get some rest and come back later. I believe, thanks to your help, I will get it. I will come back tomorrow hopefully when I have got it working. Really appreciate your help here, thank you.

Comment: Just to update you, I have found that this line `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)` evaluates to false when the page is published (not draft) so I think there lies my first issue.